# What is the correct way to use stdin, stdout, and stderr in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, popen

Does anyone have experience using the subprocess.call command in Python?
I keep getting errors whenever a line like this is in my code:

```
INFILE1 = open(script_dir+"/Scripts/plot_TSS_profile.R","r")
  subprocess.call("Rscript","--slave","--args",filenames["housekeeping_profile"]+" "+filenames["unexpressed_profile"]+" "+filenames["profile_plot"],stdin=INFILE1,  stderr=ERR_LOG,stdout=OUT_LOG,shell=True)
   INFILE1.close().
```

If I leave the code as is, I get an error that the program finds multiple values for each th stdin, stderr, and stdout for some reason even though those are the only ones in the code. If I take out these parameters and just put the infile early in the brackets after “--args”, it doesn’t seem to read the file as it says the ‘buffer should be an integer.’

For example, this way gives the buffer error:

```
INFILE1 = script_dir+"/Scripts/plot_TSS_profile.R"
    subprocess.call("Rscript",INFILE1,"--slave","--args",filenames["housekeeping_profile"]+" "+filenames["unexpressed_profile"]+" "+filenames["profile_plot"],stderr=ERR_LOG,shell=True)
    INFILE1.close()
```

Here are my error outputs for more specific information:

The one on buffsize:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/work1/users/pughlab/projects/IEG_MiSEQ/Inferring_DNA_Expression/ExpressionPrediction-master/expression_prediction.py", line 277, in

```
    step5(ERR_LOG,OUT_LOG,args,proj_dir,script_dir,filenames)
  File "/mnt/work1/users/pughlab/projects/IEG_MiSEQ/Inferring_DNA_Expression/ExpressionPrediction-master/expression_prediction.py", line 165, in step5
    subprocess.call("Rscript",INFILE1,"--slave","--args",filenames["housekeeping_profile"]+" "+filenames["unexpressed_profile"]+" "+filenames["profile_plot"],stderr=ERR_LOG,shell=True)
  File "/mnt/work1/software/centos7/python/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/mnt/work1/software/centos7/python/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 343, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
```

And the other error on there being multiple values:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/work1/users/pughlab/projects/IEG_MiSEQ/Inferring_DNA_Expression/ExpressionPrediction-master/expression_prediction.py", line 272, in <module>
    step5(ERR_LOG,OUT_LOG,args,proj_dir,script_dir,filenames)
  File "/mnt/work1/users/pughlab/projects/IEG_MiSEQ/Inferring_DNA_Expression/ExpressionPrediction-master/expression_prediction.py", line 165, in step5
    subprocess.call("Rscript","--slave","--args",filenames["housekeeping_profile"]+" "+filenames["unexpressed_profile"]+" "+filenames["profile_plot"],stdin=INFILE1,stderr=ERR_LOG,stdout=OUT_LOG,shell=True)
  File "/mnt/work1/software/centos7/python/2.7.15/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'stdin'
```

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The main problem is that `call` takes a *list* of arguments or a *single* string to be parsed by the shell. You don't appear to need `shell=True` here; just create a single list of all the positional arguments you attempting to pass.

```
with open(script_dir+"/Scripts/plot_TSS_profile.R","r") as INFILE1:
    cmd = [
        "Rscript",
        "--slave",
        "--args",
        filenames["housekeeping_profile"], 
        filenames["unexpressed_profile"],
        filenames["profile_plot"]
    ]
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdin=INFILE1, stderr=ERR_LOG, stdout=OUT_LOG)
```

Passing multiple positional arguments means that parameters that were meant to be set via keyword arguments (like `stdin`, etc) are being assigned values that were meant as part of the command to execute.

Comment: Thank you for this! It was very helpful.